# Heroku - Disable Postgresql SSL?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku, postgis, geoserver

I have a PostGIS database on Heroku and I want to connect my external GeoServer to it. I can't do it because Geoserver does not support SSL and Heroku requires it.

Is there any way of disabling Heroku postgres SSL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplified GeoServer UI does not allow to configure SSL connections, but you can setup a JNDI connection pool and provide all JDBC parameters you want that way:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/tomcat-jndi/tomcat-jndi.html#configuring-a-postgresql-connection-pool

Answer (score 0):

If you do run into a client that doesn't support SSL *at* *all*, you can possibly proxy it using a tool like `stunnel`.